# Setting the text on UIButtonLabel on a PLUICameraViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, iphone-privateapi

I'm trying to set the text of the "Retake" and "Use" buttons on the `PLUICameraViewController`. I've programmatically navigated through the view hierarchy and found a few `UIButtonLabel` objects. Logging the text of these shows what I expect: "Retake", "Cancel" etc. However setting the text doesn't work. The buttons just keep their original text. Here's what I've tried:

```
if (q is a subclass of UIButtonLabel)
    if ([q respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)])
        [q performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"zzz"];
```

The code runs w/o crashing. Also respondsToSelector is returning YES. **How can I make the text on the buttons update?**

By the way I'm aware of other approaches involving custom buttons, my own views etc. I'm really curious from an Objective-C/runtime/iOS perspective why the above code doesn't work.

Also note I'm doing this in

```
 navigationController:willShowViewController:viewController:animated:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I don't think it's an issue of Private APIs, *per se*.  This is just the way `UIButton` works.

Yes, the title of the button is a `UILabel`, and in practice, it is probably/currently an instance of the private class [UIButtonLabel](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIButtonLabel.h).  But, the way Apple intends for you to change the title text is to use the methods in `UIButton` itself:

```
[self.button setTitle: @"newTitle" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button setTitle: @"newTitle" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

instead of trying to drill down into the button's subview heirarchy, find a button label, and call `setText:`.

[Here's the relevant API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle%3aforState%3a)

As to *why* it doesn't work, I suppose that's because Apple wants it that way.

For one, changing a button's title is expected to be a normal use case.  So, for convenience, they probably wanted to give you an easy method to call, directly in the `UIButton` interface.  If they forced you do drill down into the view hierarchy, not only would you have to write more code, but it makes it a little harder for Apple to change the underlying implementation of a button.  They may want to preserve the ability to change it later, and for that, it's better for them to keep some sort of wrapper APIs at the `UIButton` level.

Also, if you directly change the text on the button label, you are circumventing their design, where the label text depends on the button **state** (e.g. normal, highlighted, selected, etc.)  Even though most people probably use the same button text for all states, the design allows for state-dependent text, and therefore, hiding the underlying `UIButtonLabel` helps enforce this design.

That's my guess as to their motivation.

So, to enforce this, it's entirely possible that in their implementation of `UIButtonLabel` `setText:`, they decline to update the text after the button has been initialized.  After that, you have to use the `setTitle:forState:` method.

Comment: Awesome! Casting `PLCropOverlayBottomBarButton` etc to `UIButton` and setting the title via `setTitle:forState:` works! I'll assign the bounty after the timeout period :-)